# Are literal suffixes needed in standard C?

Tags: c, c99

There is a question already answering the particular case of variable declaration, but what about other literal constant uses?

For example:

```
uint64_t a;
...
int32_t b = a / 1000000000;
```

Is last piece of code equivalent to next one in any standard C compiler?

```
uint64_t a;
...
int32_t b = (int32_t)(a / UINT64_C(1000000000));
```

In other words, are xINTn_C macros needed at all (supposing we are using explicit casting in cases where implicit one is wrong)?

**EDIT**

When compiler reads `1000000000`, is it allowed to store it as `int` in an internal representation (dropping all overflowing bits) or it must store it at highest possible precision (long long) until it resolves whole expression type? Is it an implementation-defined behavior or it is mandated by the standard?

Comment: It is not good to edit your question so that it invalidates points made in existing answers.

Comment: Also, I'm curious why you ask about the old C99 standard rather than just 'generic C' or the C11 standard.  Granted, the `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` facilities were not part of C90, but C99 is pretty old now, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I fixed edit issue. I'm asking about C99 because is the most widely supported standard after ANSI C and is the one I'm using. World would be nicer if all compilers support C11, but this is not the case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example isn't valid C99 and looks like C++.  Perhaps want you want is a cast, i.e. `(int32_t)(a / UINT64_C(1000000000))`?

Is there a difference between `a / UINT64_C(1000000000)` and `a / 1000000000`?  No, they'll end up with the same operation.  But I don't think that's really your question.

I think your question boils down to what will the type of the integer literal "1000000000" be?  Will it be an int32_t or an int64_t?  The answer in C99 comes from §6.4.4.1 paragraph 5:

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.

For decimal constants with no suffix, the list is `int`, `long int`, `long long int`.  So the first literal will almost certainly be an `int` (depend on the size of an `int`, which will likely be 32-bits and therefor large enough to hold one billion).  The second literal with the UINT64_C macro will likely be either a `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, depending on the platform.  It will be whatever type corresponds to `uint64_t`.

So the types of the constants are not the same.  The first will be signed while the second is unsigned.  And the second will most likely have more "longs", depending on the compiler's sizes of the basic int types.

In your example, it makes no difference that the literals have different types because the `/` operator will need to promote the literal to the type of `a` (because `a` will be of equal or greater rank than the literal in any case).  Which is why I didn't think that was really your question.

For an example of why `UINT64_C()` would matter, consider an expression where the result changes if the literals are promoted to a larger type.  I.e., overflow will occur in the literals' native types.

```
int32_t a = 10;
uint64_t b = 1000000000 * a;  // overflows 32-bits
uint64_t c = UINT64_C(1000000000) * a; // constant is 64-bit, no overflow
```

To compute `c`, the compiler will need to promote `a` to `uint64_t` and perform a 64-bit multiplication.  But to compute `b` the compiler will use 32-bit multiplication since both values are 32-bits.

In the last example, one could use a cast instead of the macro:

```
uint64_t c = (uint_least64_t)(1000000000) * a;
```

That would also force the multiplication to be at least 64 bits.

Why would you ever use the macro instead of casting a literal?  One possibility is because decimal literals are signed.  Suppose you want a constant that isn't representable as a signed value?  For example:

```
uint64_t x = (uint64_t)9888777666555444333;    // warning, literal is too large
uint64_t y = UINT64_C(9888777666555444333);    // works
uint64_t z = (uint64_t)(9888777666555444333U); // also works
```

Another possibility is for preprocessor expressions.  A cast isn't legal syntax for use in the expression of a `#if` directive.  But the `UINTxx_C()` macros are.

Since the macros use suffixes pasted onto literals and there is no suffix for a short, one will likely find that UINT16_C(x) and UINT32_C(x) are identical.  This gives the result that `(uint_least16_t)(65537) != UINT16_C(65537)`.  Not what one might expect.  In fact, I have a hard time seeing how this complies with C99 §7.18.4.1:

> The macro UINTN_C(value) shall expand to an integer constant expression corresponding to the type uint_leastN_t.

Comment: Given `uint16_t x;` would compilers be likely to issue diagnostics for `x=UINT16_C(65539);` that they would not issue for `x=65539;`?  The latter would have defined behavior (set x to 3), but in some cases a diagnostic might be more meaningful.

Comment: `UINT16_C(65539)` is unsigned while `65539` is signed, so one could get a implicit signed to unsigned conversion diagnostic with the latter.   More relevant would the overflow in the implicit conversion of the literal to a uint16_t, and one will get that in either case.  It would not be generated with `x=(uint16_t)65539;` as the conversion is no longer implicit.