# Suffixes for integer types

Tags: c, integer

Why do we use suffixes for integer types?
Can suffixes determine the integer type?

```
e.g.

long int a;
a = 50000LL;
```

Is variable a now long integer or long long integer?

Comment: This is best answered by the relevant [standard section](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1)

Comment: @EugeneSh. - The link _seems_ to go nowhere.

Comment: As an example, you may get a warning if you assign `0x80000000` to `uint32_t num`.  One way to eliminate this is like this: `0x80000000U`.

Comment: @ryyker Just verified. It goes straight where it should. What are you getting?

Comment: @FiddlingBits For 32-bit `int` system `0x80000000` will have `unsigned int` type.

Comment: When used in various expressions, the types of integer values matter—what happens when a value is shifted or used in a bit-wise complement or other operations depends on its type. The suffixes give some control over what type the value has. Assigning a value to an object does not alter the type of the object.

Comment: @EugeneSh. -  My screen froze, then got a times out message.  Its on my side.  Probably an over-zealous security protocol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we put suffixes following numeric literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242582/why-do-we-put-suffixes-following-numeric-literals)

Comment: so many duplicates: [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134956/995714), [Are literal suffixes needed in standard C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43193065/995714), [Why do you need to append an L or F after a value assigned to a C++ constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380653/995714), [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13134956/995714), [Are long-suffix and unsigned-suffix needed when declaring long literals in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/975942/995714)

Answer (score 3):

> Why do we use suffixes for integer types?

To define the *minimum* width type and/or make unsigned the constant.

---

With bit shifting (Assume 32-bit `int`) `1u << 31` is good.  `1 << 31` is UB (shifting into sign bit). [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59256576/suffixes-for-integer-types/59256761#comment104722932_59256761)

To form desired constants:

```
// Assume `long` is 32-bit
long long x = 12345678912345L; // Constant is LL due to range.
long long y = 1000LL * 1000 * 1000 * 1000; // y gets the expected value
long long z = 1000L * 1000 * 1000 * 1000; // UB due to long overflow.
```

> Can suffixes determine the integer type?

Yes.  A `u` indicates some *unsigned* type.  Useful also with macro processing.

`l`, `ll` indicate at *least* a `long`, `long long` type.  Not useful with macro processing as preprocessor arithmetic done in `intmax_t/uintmax_t` regardless of the `l, ll` suffix.

> Is variable `a` now `long` integer or `long long` integer?

`a` is declared as a `long int`.  Its type does not change due to any assignment.

Answer (score 0):

*Why do we use suffixes for integer types? Can suffixes determine the integer type?*

*[From here:](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/integer-literal-in-c-cpp-prefixes-suffixes/)*

> ...Integer literal is a type of literal for an integer whose value is
>   directly represented in source code...

- **Prefixes**: They are basically represent in four types.
  1) **Decimal-literal(base 10)**`:- a non-zero decimal digit followed by zero or more decimal digits(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9). For example, 56, 78.`

  2)  **Octal-literal(base 8)** `:- a zero followed by zero or more octal digits(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). For example, 045, 076, 06210.`
  3)  **Hex-literal(base 16)** `:- 0x or 0X followed by one or more hexadecimal digits(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, A, b, B, c, C, d, D, e, E, f, F).   For example, 0x23A, 0Xb4C, 0xFEA.`
  4)  **Binary-literal(base 2)** `:- 0b or 0B followed by one or more binary digits(0, 1). For example, 0b101, 0B111.`
- Suffixes: They are represented in many ways according to their data types.
  1)        **int**:- No suffix are required because integer constant are by default assigned as int data type.
  2)   **unsigned int**: character u or U at the end of integer constant.
  3)         **long int**: character l or L at the end of integer constant.
  4)         **unsigned long int**: character ul or UL at the end of integer constant.
  5)         **long long int**: character ll or LL at the end of integer constant.
  6)         **unsigned long long int**: character ull or ULL at the end of integer constant.